# How should I mount a 1x6 valance board to my ceiling for curtains?

Tags: ceiling, carpentry, curtain-rail

I am trying to hang a 1x6 from my ceiling to make a wall-length cornice box for blackout curtains. I'm stuck on the best way to attach the wood to the ceiling. I will be mounting two curtain tracks between the box and the wall. The wall is about 11 ft long. The rafters are perpendicular to the wall.

The 1x6 is basically just a full wall-length valance or cornice box. I want to space it 4-6 inches from the wall, running the full length of the wall.

I'm using dual ceiling-mounted curtain tracks--one for a sheer curtain, one for a blackout curtain. They are each roughly 1" wide.

- Pocket screws might work but could be hard to line up with the rafters.
- L brackets might work but I'm worried about them bending over time.
- I could hang a few pieces of 2x4 to the ceiling and screw the 1x6 into that but it could/will seriously impact how far away from the wall I hang box due to the curtain tracks. I'd like to keep this close to the wall, within 6" or so.

Comment: Please put all information in your question. See [ask] and take the [tour]. I'm not sure you answered my questions, though.

Comment: Why do you need to hang it from the ceiling at all—won't it be attached to the walls too?

Comment: @Huesmann Yes, I'm going to use at least one L bracket on the bottom to attach it to the wall.  Should I use more?  I'm not sure that 4 L brackets on the wall would hold it securely enough.  What are your thoughts?  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Vince if you have it suitably anchored to the wall, I don't think there's a need to anchor it to the ceiling too.  Will the valances be supported by the floor, or do they need to be suspended above carpet or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with either a ceiling cleat or the brackets.

2x2 cleats would be fine and easy to work with. If you need them to be lower profile, 1x2 could work, but it takes more precision to mount to a 3/4" board. You could also use a *wider* cleat, say a 2x4, then mount the curtain track to that. I'm not sure how it'll all fit, so you'll have to work that out.

Angle brackets have few good uses, in my opinion, but this is one of them. You could mount your valance with brackets every 24-32" and then lay the curtain channel right over them if you want.

Comment: Thanks!  You convinced me to try the L brackets.  It will save me from drilling and patching the face.  I think if I add one on the bottom against each wall, it will keep the board from bending.  I think 6-8 brackets should be able to hold it snug against the ceiling anyway.  Thanks again!